# OpenUI5 Scroll issue on BlackBerry Z10

Tags: scroll, blackberry, sapui5

I've noticed that scrolling for example a sap.m.List on BlackBerry Z10 is very laggy. The same code is running fine on devices with similar hardware like Galaxy S4 Mini. I'm using a default sap.m.List with 30 StandardListItems. I've tested it inside a cordova container and inside the default browser. Both variants are very laggy. Is it a general BlackBerry problem? Could anyone double check it?

I found out that this is related to the "**touchmove**" event which is getting fired much more than on the other devices/platforms.

BlackBerry Z10 Console output (touchmove event getting fired 500 times!!)

[BlackBerry console output](http://postimg.org/image/o6ekvzudn)

Android console output (touchmove event getting fired 2 times)

[Android console output](http://postimg.org/image/4ailggdcb/)

Thanks and best regards

Comment: You can also check it with the following example app [link](http://output.jsbin.com/xuyimuruta)